# Undefined method `upvote_by' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are the same problem, but answers are not good for my code. Error is still there.
I reinstall gem, try different versions, and I think add methods in before_action properly and problem is still there.

```
   class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
       helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
       before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :like, :unlike]
       before_action only: [:like, :unlike]
   ...

   def like
      @article.upvote_by current_user
      redirect_to articles_path
   end

   def unlike
      @article.downvote_by current_user
      redirect_to articles_path
   end
  ...
```

And html

```
  <%= link_to "Like", like_article_path(article), class: 'like_url', method: :put %>
```

When click on it.

undefined method `upvote_by' for nil:NilClass

Comment: When you see an error like this, think to yourself: "What is `nil`?" -- It must be whatever variable you're calling the `upvote_by` method on, which in this case is `@article`. So the "real" bug is that `@article == nil`. Therefore you must either not be assigning the variable in the first place, or the thing that you *think* assigns the variable isn't working as you expect. In the above code you showed us, there's nothing that attempts to define the `@article` variable -- which leads me to assume you're not defining it.

Comment: *Maybe* you actually meant to do something like  `before_action :set_article, only: [:like, :unlike]`? You have a suspicious empty line there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find your `Article` first:

```
def like
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end

def unlike
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

You can also extract article finding to `before_action`

```
before_action :find_article, only: %i[like unlike] # whatever you please

# ...

private

def find_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```